# increase geo corrdinates such that nearest points can be found

Tags: python, django, api, geolocation, geo

I am working on a project which uses external API for fetching nearby shops for given *Geo coordinates* now the problem, if in case there is now shop available for given coordinates we should still be able to retrieve any of its nearest locations for shops that means we possibly have to increase coordinates`(lat_coord,long_coord)` periodically until we find such shops or locations(shops) which also means we're increasing the (**GPS radius**), now my question is whether there any such algorithm available which does such thing, also is my approach correct in this case because i am increasing the amount of API hits

```
def get_nearby_stores(member_id,lat,lon):
   api = B2C
   response , status_code = api.get_nearest_location_shop(
        member_id=member_id,
        lat=lat,
```

Comment: What API are you talking about? The question is, when I call this API how can I get the closest result no matter the distance?

Comment: API is not the matter of concern, my main point is how do i increase Geo codes (radius) by increments because increasing radius means i am getting nearer to what ever location API gets me in return @IainShelvington

Comment: "API is not the matter of concern" but you are not passing a radius or longitude to the API, it's not clear what you mean by increasing the "radius"

Comment: by radius i mean we're increasing values for coordinates in every direction on `x-y plane` for e.g `(50,60)` and `(-50,-60)` , i may not be familiar with conventions used in Geo coordinate system but that is where i am going, and while we're increasing values for these coordinates at the same time we 're feeding them to the API function which returns us minimum locations(if available)

Comment: So your question is actually, how do I generate longitude/latitude coordinates that spiral outwards from a starting point?

Comment: exactly bru @IainShelvington you're genius , is there any algo for that